# Can't find CSS Colour in Dev Tools

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome-devtools

I have a simple, static website built using BS4. On this site I use their default:

```
navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark
```

Navbar for mobile. This is a simple hamburger menu in mobile. When the hamburger icon is in its `;focus` state, the outline of the hamburger menu changes to a different colour, this outline feature can be disabled as follows:

```
    .navbar-toggler:focus,
.navbar-toggler:active,
.navbar-toggler-icon:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

I wanted to disable this to remove an orange colour I couldn't find in my CSS but didn't have time to hunt down so just disabled it altogether- however, I now realise this colour is proving impossible to find.

This colour in question has the hex code #e59700 (found using colourpicker). Absolutely nowhere on the entire site, in any CSS, html, or CDN hosted stylesheet can I find this hexcode, it is an orange colour and I searched for "orange" just in case to no avail.

I both searched my CSS & HTML manually in NotePad++ as well as using Ctrl Shift F (Dev tools search). Every single other colour used on the site can be found through this search, even those hosted on bootstraps CDN style-sheets.

I am completely and utterly lost, this isn't a caching issue as it appears on multiple devices after multiple hard refreshes. Any ideas?

EDIT: I have also tried searching in both the RGB and HSL colourspaces to no avail.

Comment: I can't resist: have you tried looking for `color`?!? :)

Comment: What do you mean? If you mean colour/color then yes.

Comment: Ignore that...  orange (in Chrome, desktop, html) is `#FFA500` - created a div, set it's backgroundColor style to orange, inspected it, and that's what I've got back.  I know yellow is full red and full green and no blue, so I tried half green - #FF8000 and it was pretty close.  Is this what you were asking?

Comment: It's alright, I solved it. The colour #E59700 is -webkit-focus-ring-color, it's a OS based webkit colour not site specific.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

By default, webkit browsers use outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;.

On Macs -webkit-focus-ring-color is blue rgb(94, 158, 214) (or #5E9ED6), but on Windows and Linux it’s gold rgb(229, 151, 0) **(or #E59700)**

Essentially, if I force :focus on any object on the page it'll be given the -webkit-focus-ring-color which is #E59700.

Answer (score 1):

When in your site view, the frontend will be rendering the color into something on the browser. Normally the rendering development tools will be delivering *some* CSS, and modern browsers will have a way to traverse this.

In Chrome you can do the following:

1. Press `F12` to open the Devtools Menu
   [image: picture of dev box]
2. In the Devtools menu, press "Inspect element", then click on the orange element on your page
   [image: Highlighting the inspect element tool]
3. Navigate to the "Styles" pane: you will see it shows the CSS values and from where they come from
   [image: Css styles and where to find them]
4. Click on the URL formatted text in the section containing your orange color.
   [image: Your colour here]
5. As you are using a framework, it may or may not be a minified CSS document (`file.min.css`, for example). In that case for legibility you can prettify it by pressing the button at the bottom.
   [image: Prettify me, captain!]
6. From there you will have the frontend rendering of your code and the source of where it is served from. Depending on your framework, you will be able to use the file which this is from to make the change you want to see in your code.
   [image: The CSS found]